# Creating a priority wifi list in connman

Tags: wifi, utilities, priority, connman

I'm using connman to manage my network connectivity on an embedded device (Beagle Bone Green Wireless).

I've been able to connect to networks and save those networks for future use but I'm having trouble setting up some sort of access point priority list. For example lets say I have this:

Wifi1 - priority 1 Wifi2 - priority 2 Wifi3 - priority 3 Wifi4 - priority 4

I want connman to try connecting to wifi1 first. If it fails I'd like it try connecting to wifi2...etc

How can this be accomplished?

I've tried looking into editing the connman config file but I can't find any options to set the access point priority.

There is an option for favorite but it seems to be a true/false setting.